# I can't align the logo with the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I am following a youtube tutorial and I wrote the exact same code but I can't get my logo to align with the navigation like theirs

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> STUDENT HUB </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="image/logo.png" width="125px" alt="this is an image">
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Commu</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Report</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
      <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried using vertical-align: center and Display: inline-block  under the navbar selector but it didn't work either

Comment: `navbar` div should also consist `nav`. Close its div where nav element ends and all will be good

Comment: <div class="navbar"> div close after </nav> tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your `nav` tag inside the `navbar` div.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
}

p {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> STUDENT HUB </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="image/logo.png" width="125px" alt="this is an image">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Commu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are answering a trivial question that can be closed as a typo-type question - the answer is already in the comments to the question and you could have voted to close

Comment: But it did get your attention. It is not personal. But posting an answer to tell a `</div>` has to be moved a few lines and letting 4 others do the same instead of just commenting and voting to close is not a great attitude either.

Comment: @mplungjan, I felt an answer was needed and not a comment, thus I answered. Anyways, you have done what you thought was right, doesn't matter anymore, forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<nav>
        <ul>
          <li><img src="image/logo.png" width="125px" alt="this is an image"></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Commu</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
            <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **move** your  closing tag of the navBar **under** the nav closing tag

Answer (score 0):

you have done it almost correctly. Just move the nav tag into div

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> STUDENT HUB </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="image/logo.png" width="125px" alt="this is an image">
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Commu</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  

  .navbar_container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  nav {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
  }
  
  p {
    color: #555;
  }
```

```html
<div class="navbar_container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="logo">
            <img src="image/logo.png" width="125px" alt="this is an image">
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Commu</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Help </a></li>
            <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
</div>
```